# VBA/Excel If...Then...ElseIf...Else Statement copy down column issue

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

Okay, I have the statement figured out, it works just how I need it to. When I run it, it pretty much looks for the Interior.Color and if it matches it gives me the Text value of said cell color. How do I copy and paste this If Statement down the entire column as long as there's data?

I do not know the VBA version for this. So the VBA Code I have looks like this:

```
If Range("F2").Interior.Color = 255 Then
Range("AE2") = "Red"
ElseIf Range("F2").Interior.Color = 65252 Then
Range("AE2") = "Green"
Else
Range("AE2") = "New"
End If
```

I want that entire statement to be copied down column AE until there's no data in column F (Copy/Paste) but it changes accordingly, and follows the cells down.

Hopefully I'm making sense.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you didn't mention which Column holds data, I assumed it's **Column F**, you can modify the code easily according to your needs.

I also switched your `IFs` to `Select Case`, if in the future you will have more conditions to test.

```
' assuming your column that has data is Column F >> modify it according to your needed column
lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).row

For lRow = 2 To lastRow
    Select Case Range("F" & lRow).Interior.Color
        Case 255
            Range("AE" & lRow) = "Red"

        Case 65252
            Range("AE" & lRow) = "Red"

        Case Else
            Range("AE" & lRow) = "New"

    End Select
Next lRow
```

Comment: Column F has the colored cells and Column AE has the result. So, all I want essentially is for excel to tell me the color of the cell. Does that help?

Comment: @user4223089 not exactly, does column F also has text inside ? if not,  which column from your entire range holds data ? does one of the columns from F to AE holds related data ?

Comment: So, column F has data and a fill color (Red, Yellow, or Green). My IF Statment from above tells me exactly if it's either of those color codes, if not then it says "New". So all works great, I just need to copy and paste it down the entire column, which is column AE.

Comment: @user4223089 OK then. so my code in the answer fits, have you tested it ?

Comment: Just tested again, and it works! how the heck do you know this stuff? I am honestly very frustrated that I cannot seem to get this VBA thing. I am in absolute love with it, but I just cant seem to wrap my head around it. Never even heard of Case or Select within VBA, sounds almost like SQL but i'll look at the code and do a little research on both to understand it. Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: @user4223089 there is a new Beta documentation section in SO site, check it out for some nice tricks. It will be updated with more stuff with time